# standalone.sh scanning for RHAMT for dot release upgrades?

Tags: rhamt

Is there standalone.sh scanning for RHAMT? So can there be flags for what has changed in a newer version of a dot release from say EAP 7.0 to 7.1?

Answer (score 0):

RHAMT does not currently scan the server configuration.